# If two fields have default values

Tags: jquery, webforms

I'm trying to make it to where when a user clicks a button and if two input fields both have their default values, to remove classes from those input fields.

Currently however I can only get it to work with one field, not multiple fields.

Any ideas? http://jsfiddle.net/3xaBs

Thanks!

Comment: Remove classes completely or remove a particular class?

Comment: To further AlienWebguy's point, what happens if an input has more than one class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like [it works for me](http://jsfiddle.net/vol7ron/3xaBs/2/):

```
$('#button').click(function() {
   var one = $("#fone");
   var two = $("#ftwo");

   if (  one.val() == one[0].defaultValue
      && two.val() == two[0].defaultValue ){
       one.removeClass('myclass'); 
       two.removeClass('anotherclass'); 
   }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
$('#button').click(function() {
    if ($("#fone").val() == 'Hello World' && $("#ftwo").val() == 'Lorem Ipsum'){
        $('#fone').removeClass('myclass'); 
        $('#ftwo').removeClass('myclass'); 
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a scalable solution. You can as many fields as you wantand it will only clear the classes if all fields in the group have their default value on submit:

**HTML** - take advantage of custom data attributes so you can group the fields without assigning a class which JQuery will remove:

```
<input type="text" id="fone" name="fone" class="myclass" data-group="my_fields" data-default="Hello World" value="Hello World" />
<input type="text" id="ftwo" name="ftwo" class="anotherclass" data-group="my_fields" data-default="Lorem Ipsum" value="Lorem Ipsum" />

<a href="#" id="button">Link</a>
```

**JQuery** - Grab the fields in the group, compare their current value to their default value, and increment the counter, compare against the number of fields total:

```
$('#button').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var default_count = 0;
    $('input[data-group=my_fields]').each(function(){
       if($(this).val() == $(this).data('default'))
       {
           default_count++;
       } 
    });

    // If all fields have default value still...
    if(default_count == $('input[data-group=my_fields]').length)
    {
       $('input[data-group=my_fields]').removeClass(); // remove all classes
    }
});
```

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/AlienWebguy/3xaBs/5/